# Getting all relationships among neighbors of a node

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have an embedded graph db of nodes (twitter users) and directed edges (follows).

I'm trying to get all relationships among the users (Set A) who are followed by a specified user (Node U). Also the relationships between the nodes in `A` and the specified node `U`.

My query:

```
START u=node:user_id(user_id={id_of_U})
MATCH p = u-->following, p2= following-[?]->u, p3 = following-[?]->()<--u
RETURN distinct rels(p),rels(p2),rels(p3)
```

This query gives me what I expect but the problem is, it takes so much time when the specified user is following too many users.

I tried lots of queries and the query above is the best one so far. Yet, I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do this, because when I get those relationships in a java method by walking through all users in "A",  getting all relationships for each of them (Direction.BOTH), and then filtering the relationships with "A" (remove relationships that have start or end node that does not belong to "A"), it takes just 8 secs for a user following 500 people, whereas the cypher query cannot even fail without blowing my heap up...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one?

```
start u=node:user_id(user_id={id_of_U})
MATCH u-[r]->following
with u, r, following
match following-[r2?]->u, following-[r3?]->()<-[r4]-u
RETURN distinct r, r2, r3, r4
```

Also, are you using the latest 1.9?

Comment: I was using 1.8.1 but now upgraded to 1.9 and tried your query, nothing changed though...

Answer (score 0):

starting with `p = u-->following` is not optimal, since it takes all related nodes and later on you try to filter on these nodes. i'd suggest to pick up less nodes and later on expand this set a little bit:

```
START u=node:user_id(user_id={id_of_U})
MATCH u-[:FOLLOWS]->following
WITH u,following
MATCH u-[r]-following
RETURN distinct r;
```

this will give you all the relationships between nodes in setA who are also folowed by node U.

in case you dont have the relationship FOLLOW in your graph - you should have, otherwise you graph design is'nt optimal. i noticed you are not using any specific rel type in your query - this can be optimal if and only if you have just 1 relationship type in your data. as far as i understand your question, you got more than 1 rel type.

**edit:**

```
START u=node:user_id(user_id={id_of_U})
MATCH u-[]-following
WITH u, following
MATCH u-[r]-again, again-[r2]-following
RETURN r, r2
```

Comment: Your query is giving only the relationships between `u` and `following`... What I want is also to get all relationships between `following[m]`-`following[n]` where `following[m]` and `following[n]` are elements of set `A`. And that's the tricky part that I can't handle.  (btw, my graph has one type of relationship, FOLLOWS)

Comment: thx, i've updated my answer, the point is to match the setA two times into two different variables and then match also the rels between those variables. in case this will still reach you heap limit i'm afraid the only way to go through this is to use gremlin and strictly define the algorithm.

Comment: actually the query you suggested caused an heap error but adding one more `WITH` solved that problem. `START u=node:user_id(user_id='109537107')  MATCH u-[]->following  WITH u, following  MATCH u-[r]->again  WITH following,again,r  MATCH again-[r3]->following  RETURN r,r3`   however, I made another implementation that first I get all ids of nodes that `u` follows. then pass them twice as parameter like `START u=node({nodeIdList}), u2= node({nodeIdList2})  MATCH u-[r]->u2, u2-[r2]->u  RETURN distinct r,r2`  this provided the fastest solution. maybe we should wait for new versions of neo4j...

Comment: but your suggestion to use `WITH` is important and made me understand the way that cypher works a little bit more. thanks a lot. if no other answer can do better in a few days, I'll accept your answer as solving the problem. I just want to wait and be sure that we have no better option.

Comment: good job for upgrading the query. sometimes, some problems can not be done with neo4j in an useful way - for example when there is a super node or the number of elements matched in the query is too high - this is a computational problem, not a software one and thus i'm afraid neo4j will never get better in this. in such cases i would recommend building your own graph algorithm using gremlin, or to use a completely different technology, potentially apache hadoop with minhash on a cluster of servers.